# Which R /Python package for piece wise segmented regression with automated breakpoint detection

Tags: python, r, regression, piecewise

I'm looking for R/ Python packages that can do a segmented regression with automated breakpoint detection, report the linear segments and find out the coefficients (slope/intercept) of the linear segments in an automated way. I would prefer R packages but Python 2.7/3.X would do as well.My data looks something similar to the pic, but have hundreds of such data sets.
[image]
Thanks

Comment: you can try https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/strucchange/index.html.. if you can provide an example we can see whether it works ok

Answer (score 1):

There are some overviews of change point packages [here](https://www.marinedatascience.co/blog/2019/09/28/comparison-of-change-point-detection-methods/) and [here](https://lindeloev.github.io/mcp/articles/packages.html). Although the `segmented` package is quite capable and widely used, it does not model intercept-changes even when "told to", so be careful with that.

However, your data seems to be so regular that no inferential packages are needed for the detection of the change points, and hence not for the slopes either. The change points are simply the x-values at which y is larger than the preceding y. If `x` is your x-coordinates and `y` is your y-coordinates:

```
cps = x[which(y > dplyr::lag(y, 1))]
```

To illustrate, I simulated some data to look like yours and plot the change points on top using red lines:

```
# Simulate data
thresh = 6.95
x = seq(0, 1.5, by = 0.01)
y = c(6.98)  # starting
for (i in seq(length.out = length(x) - 1)) {
  y = c(y, y[i] -0.005)
  if (y[i+1] < thresh) {
    y[i+1] = y[i+1] + rnorm(1, 0.04, 0.01)
  }
}

# Detect change points and plot them
cps = x[which(y > dplyr::lag(y, 1))]
plot(x, y, type = "l")
abline(v = cps, col = "red")
```

[image]

Detecting the slopes is now just a matter of looping over the change points and calculating the slope of each segment.

Answer (score 1):

The [piecewise-regression package in Python](https://github.com/chasmani/piecewise-regression) or [segmented package in R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/segmented/segmented.pdf) do what your question asks for, fitting linear models and also finding breakpoint positions.